# PyQt5 button click not working

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wrote a simple code in Python GUI to calculate the tax on button click using PyQt5. It should work on button click. But button click event is not working properly. It is showing the following error.

self.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)
AttributeError: 'AppWindow' object has no attribute 'calc_tax_button'

I am using python on eclipse.

My main code till now.

```
**gu1.py**

import sys
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from design import Ui_MainWindow

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)

    def CalculateTax(self):
        price = int(self.price_box.toPlainText())
        tax = (self.tax_rate.value())
        total_price = price  + ((tax / 100) * price)
        total_price_string = "The total price with tax is: " + str(total_price)
        self.results_window.setText(total_price_string)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My design code.

```
**design.py**

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.price_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.price_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 104, 71))
        self.price_box.setObjectName("price_box")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Georgia")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.tax_rate = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.tax_rate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 220, 101, 31))
        self.tax_rate.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.tax_rate.setObjectName("tax_rate")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 230, 71, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Georgia")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.calc_tax_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.calc_tax_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 310, 101, 31))
        self.calc_tax_button.setObjectName("calc_tax_button")
        self.results_window = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.results_window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 390, 104, 71))
        self.results_window.setObjectName("results_window")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 301, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Georgia")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Price"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tax Rate"))
        self.calc_tax_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculate Tax"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sales Tax Calculator"))
```

Comment: From what I see, you are creating an object `self.ui` which is the constructor class for your GUI. So I would assume, you'd have to address your GUI and all widgets in it through that object. Maybe try  `self.ui.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)`

Comment: self.ui.calc_tax_button maybe? You dont have calcl tax button in AppWindow but have it in Ui MainWindow

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have changed it to
self.ui.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)
there is no error but when I click on the button it is showing Python has stopped working. @offeltoffel

Comment: You need to add the `.ui.` to all objects you create / reference in your `Ui_MainWindow` class. `self.price_box` -> `self.ui.price_box` and so on. If the error persists, track down on which line it happens via debug mode.

Comment: I have changed it as per your instruction. Now there is no error initially and the gui window is coming. but when I am clicking on the button in gui, still it's showing Python has stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classes generated by pyuic are intended to be used as a mixin, e.g:

```
import sys
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from design import Ui_MainWindow

    class AppWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.show()
            self.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)

        @pyqtSlot()
        def CalculateTax(self):
            price = int(self.price_box.toPlainText())
            tax = (self.tax_rate.value())
            total_price = price  + ((tax / 100) * price)
            total_price_string = "The total price with tax is: " + str(total_price)
            self.results_window.setText(total_price_string)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You tried to use it by creating a dedicated `ui` object which then holds all ui elements. That can also work, but then you need to access everything through the `ui` attribute:

```
class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.ui.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def CalculateTax(self):
        price = int(self.ui.price_box.toPlainText())
        tax = (self.ui.tax_rate.value())
        total_price = price  + ((tax / 100) * price)
        total_price_string = "The total price with tax is: " + str(total_price)
        self.ui.results_window.setText(total_price_string)
```

Comment: The decorator version is more future-proof.

Comment: @BoštjanMejak The problem doesn't have anything to do with the decorator. [Decorating a method as `@pyqtSlot()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) is not really needed in PyQt5 in most cases, tough it can have some small memory and performance benefits and allows to specify a method signature. But in this case it shouldn't make a difference. Nevertheles, I've added it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an object `self.ui` which is the constructor class for your GUI. You will have to address your GUI and all widgets in it through that object.

```
import sys
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from design import Ui_MainWindow

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def CalculateTax(self):
        price = int(self.ui.price_box.toPlainText())
        tax = (self.ui.tax_rate.value())
        total_price = price  + ((tax / 100) * price)
        total_price_string = "The total price with tax is: " + str(total_price)
        self.ui.results_window.setText(total_price_string)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed it as per your instruction. Now there is no error initially and the gui window is coming. but when I am clicking on the button in gui, I have been shown Python has stopped working.

Comment: I have fixed the code. You need to add a decorator @pyqtSlot() to the Calculate() function. Try the code now. ;)

Comment: @BoštjanMejak I can't find the location at where you have changed. I don't know where to insert @pyqtSlot().

Comment: @BoštjanMejak Thanks. I have solved the problem with your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @BoštjanMejak!

Comment: @BoštjanMejak. This answer now makes no sense, because you have removed the signal connection. The decorator is totally redundant, and does not fix anything. The real problem is caused by the first line in `CalculateTax`, which does not guard against passing an empty string to `int`, thus raising a `ValueError`. A simple fix for that would be something like `price = int(self.ui.price_box.toPlainText() or 0)`.

Comment: The OP said thank you, so I guess that was settled. Other issues are his to solve.